# Php code that explodes tags from a form, puts commas after each one and breaks them in groups

Tags: php

I have a form where I want to submit tags like this:

```
tag1
tag2
tag3
tag4
...
tag n
```

*each tag on it's own line.

I get the tags in my php page:

```
$tags = get_option('tags');
```

I now separate each tag by the new line criteria:

```
$tag = explode("\n", $tags);
```

In a loop, I echo them:

```
$i = '-1';
while(){ // usually a wordpress loop
    $i++;
    echo $tag[$i];
}
```

Finally I get:

```
Tag1
Tag2
Tag3
...
Tag n
```

Here is where I need help.

1. **I can't find a way to group tags - lets say by 3 and not explode them with every new line - "\n"
   That would enable me to get something like this:**
2. ****Automatically put a comma after each tag in each line, except the last one.**

It would be something like this:

```
Tag1, Tag2
Tag3, Tag4
....
Tag n-1, Tag n
```

Any ideas?

Ty!

Comment: Is this actual HTML tags? If not are the lengths of all tags the same?

Comment: This code should make it possible for a user to paste a number of tags in a form, and the code should split them in groups of two and add the commas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**: Sorry I didn't quite understand your question the first time. This code below should display 3 tags on each own line.

```
$totalTags = count($tag);
for ($i = 0; $i < $totalTags; $i += 3)
{
    $tagsLine = array($tag[$i]);
    isset($tag[$i + 1]) ? array_push($tagsLine, $tag[$i + 1]) : FALSE;
    isset($tag[$i + 2]) ? array_push($tagsLine, $tag[$i + 2]) : FALSE;
    echo implode(',', $tagsLine), '<br />';
}
```

So basically, you'll first need to count how many tags exist in the array and then do a for loop and at the end of the loop you use implode to "glue" 3 tags together. In case you're wondering, the two lines above the echo is to push a new element to a temporary array that will be "imploded" together. The temporary array will always contain one tag. That is, the first one on each line.

Comment: Won't insert a new line every 3 tags like he wants.

Comment: @MrGlass Thanks for telling me that. Didn't realize that's what he wants. Anyways, code updated...

Comment: Hello, ty very much for the code. It works though when it echo's I have a problem with the comma - I get "tag1 ,tag2 ,tag3" instead of "tag1, tag2, tag3" Any ideas why? Ty!

Comment: @webmasters You probably by accident added a space before the comma in the `implode()` function. Make sure your code looks like this `implode(', ', $tagsLine)` instead of this `implode(' ,', $tagsLine)`. Notice the position of the space next to the comma when the `implode()` function is called.

Comment: Ty, the sapce came from the $tags array, used explode for it and had to trim the spaces.

Answer (score 0):

You can group them on the fly.
Here's an example with using the code you provided

```
$tag = explode("\n", $tags);
$i = '-1';
$tags_in_group = 2;
while(){ // usually a wordpress loop
    $i++;
    echo $tag[$i] . !(($i + 1) % $tags_in_group) ? "\n" : ', ';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Modulus (%) operator](http://php.net/manual/en/internals2.opcodes.mod.php) to do a different operation every 3 items. WChange your while loop to something like:

```
$i=0;
while(){ // usually a wordpress loop
    if(($i+1)%3!=0) {
        echo $tag[$i] . ",";
    }
    else {
        echo $tag[i] . "\n";
    }
    $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would keep the explode, but within the loop you can one of two things.

This will display and then increment the variable. Adding in the necessary punctuation as it is displayed.

```
$i = 0;// I normally start at 0 to allow increments at the end of the loop
while(){// usually a wordpress loop
    echo $tag[$i++] . ", " $tag[$i++] . "\n";
}
```

or the below code will check the modulus of the current value and determine weather to display a comma or a line feed.

```
$i = 0;// I normally start at 0 to allow increments at the end of the loop
while(){// usually a wordpress loop
 echo $tag[$i] . ($i%2==0 ? "\n" : ", ");
$i++
//or the more readable approach
   if ($i%2==0){
      echo $tag[$i++] . "\n";
   }
   else{
    echo $tag[$i++] . ", ";
   }
}
```